# How to connect different Eureka clusters envs via one Eureka client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I have multiple Eureka clusters(diff ip's)

cluster A
cluster B
cluster C

How can I configure Eureka client(on the same JVM) to determine on real time to which Eureka cluster to approach? (without restart)

Our scenario is extracting json request on realtime and should retrieve endpoint ip via the right Eureka cluster based on the request message.

Is it possible to hold 3 Eureka context(one to each cluster)?

other suggestions?

thanks,
ray.